# Creating a dissolved buffer layer in PostgreSQL/PostGIS

Tags: postgis, buffer, dissolve

I have got a *MultiPolygons* layer to which I want to create 10 meter buffer around and then dissolve. All data are having SRID 4326.

I am new to PostgreSQL/PostGIS. I am drifting around the `ST_Buffer` and `ST_Union` commands, but not reaching to any conclusion.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE public.Buffer10mtr AS 
  SELECT ST_Union(ST_Buffer(Zone2.shape as geometry,10)as geometry) 
  FROM public.Zone2;
```

What can I change?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour.  Please [Edit] the question to indicate the problem you are encountering.  It seems as if you need to cast the ST_Buffer parameter to `geography` to get the units correct, but it's not clear whether the source is already `geography` and your `as geometry` was mean to be a cast.

Comment: Try it: CREATE TABLE public.Buffer10mtr AS SELECT ST_Union(ST_Buffer(Zone2.shape,0.00009)) as geom FROM public.Zone2;

Comment: You can also cast the geometries to geography like St_union(st_buffer(Zone2.shape::geography,buffer_distance))as geometry

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, I was really stuck in some other activity. 

I am getting following error message after running the code:
array size exceeds the maximum allowed (1073741823).

But when I limit them like for 10 or few more it works completely fine and write them as one feature.

So what I understand with it that PostGIS is uniting the whole feature layer as one feature.

And because I have a big data set so it is unable to do that.

So for it I have to look another way OR someone can help please.

Thanks.

Comment: Reset the MultiPolygon type to the Polygon using the ST_Dump function...